# System.Collections.Generic List and F#

Tags: f#

I have a C# class the returns a List, using System.Collections.Generic Lists not F# List

I want to iterate though the list to find a object or not find it.  Here is how I would do it in C#.  How would I accomplish the similar thing in F#

```
foreach (AperioCaseObj caseObj in CaseList)
{
     if (caseObj.CaseId == "")
     {    
     }
     else
     { 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example for iterating an integer generic list:

```
#light
open System.Collections.Generic

let genList = new List<int>()

genList.Add(1)
genList.Add(2)
genList.Add(3)


for x in genList do
  printf "%d" x
```

Comment: I'm new to F#. What is #light (first line in your example) for?

Answer (score 7):

```
match Seq.tryfind ((=) "") caseList with
      None -> print_string "didn't find it"
    | Some s -> printfn "found it: %s" s
```

Answer (score 4):

A C# list is called a ResizeArray in F#. To find an element within the ResizeArray you can use "tryfind" or "find". TryFind returns an option type (Option), which means if the element is not found, you'll get None.  Find on the other hand raises an exception if it doesn't find the element you're looking for

---

```
let foo() = 
   match CaseList |> ResizeArray.tryfind (fun x -> x.caseObj = "imlookingforyou") with
   |None -> print-string ""notfound
   |Some(case ) -> printfn "found %s" case
```

or

```
let foo()
   try
      let case = ResizeArray.find (fun x -> x.caseObj = "imlookingforyou") 
      printfn "found %s" case 

   with
   | _ -> print_string "not found"
```

---

Answer (score 2):

That kind of list is also an IEnumerable so you can still use F#'s `for elt in list do` notation:

```
for caseObj in CaseList do
  if caseObj.CaseId = "" then
    ...
  else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tryfind to match against a field in a record:

```
type foo = {
    id : int;
    value : string;
}

let foos = [{id=1; value="one"}; {id=2; value="two"}; {id=3; value="three"} ]

// This will return Some foo
List.tryfind (fun f -> f.id = 2) foos

// This will return None
List.tryfind (fun f -> f.id = 4) foos
```